# Sort table rows DESC by date column, without plugins

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I sort table rows DESC by date column, without plugins?
I've searched google, but only found plugin solutions.
**HTML Example:**

```
<html>
<body>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <th>Date</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><input value="01/01/2010"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input value="01/01/2012"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input value="01/01/2011"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input value="01/01/2013"></td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

**JSFiddle:**
http://jsfiddle.net/6o4tfxo0/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work for descending with jquery:

```
$('tr').sort(function(a,b){
    return new Date($(a).find('input').val()).getTime() < new Date($(b).find('input').val()).getTime() 
}).appendTo('tbody')
```

Comment: OoOh my gawwwwwwwwwwwd! Simple like that? Thank you very much, juvian, you rocks!!!!!!!!!

Comment: You are selecting TRs and appending to body? Hows that gonna work? Not 100% sure but don't you need to append them to **tbody** and remove old ones?

Comment: What if I want it ascending?

Comment: @BernardoLima change < to >

Comment: @Vladimirs yeah, should be tbody, fixed

Comment: @BernardoLima you need to include jquery ;)

Comment: Nevermind, @Vladimirs was right, that fixed the error! Love you guys!