# Sort html table rows by first date column with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have table with two date columns in each row start date and end date
I want to sort table rows by start date with jQuery

Below is the table html code:

```
<table class="table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr class="Headers">
      <th>Number</th>
      <th>Date Start</a></th>
      <th>Date End</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="Entries" data-id="13">
      <td data-field-type="string">1234</td>
      <td data-field-type="date">01-04-2015</td>
      <td data-field-type="date">01-04-2015</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="Entries" data-id="24">
      <td data-field-type="string">1352</td>
      <td data-field-type="date">04-10-2012</td>
      <td data-field-type="date">23-10-2015</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="Entries" data-id="8">
      <td data-field-type="string">1124</td>
      <td data-field-type="date">13-05-2014</td>
      <td data-field-type="date">01-04-2015</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="Entries" data-id="23">
      <td data-field-type="string">1652</td>
      <td data-field-type="date">07-11-2013</td>
      <td data-field-type="date">22-10-2015</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I made a try with similar solution posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27022535/sort-table-rows-desc-by-date-column-without-plugins) but without success.
 [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8Lnfq844/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest:

```
$('tr.Entries').each(function() {
     var t = this.cells[1].textContent.split('-');
     $(this).data('_ts', new Date(t[2], t[1]-1, t[0]).getTime());
}).sort(function (a, b) {
    return $(a).data('_ts') < $(b).data('_ts');
}).appendTo('tbody');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rmva17gr/

Comment: Thank you wery much for your suggest! I would like to ask is posible with jQuery to sort html table rows by two cells e.g. by  first cell name and then by second cell date  something like in MYSQL ORDER BY name,date DESC so rows will be grupped by same name in date sort.

Comment: @stav You are welcome! JavaScript doesn't work like SQL but the `sort` method itself is flexible enough for doing what you want, here  is a demo: http://jsbin.com/nuvudaboto/1/edit?html,js,output. Basically it sorts by the the second cells and then by the first cells.

Comment: Maybe i must post this as new question but ill ask here. I inverted your code sorts by first cell and then by second cell but i can't make it work :(. Here is demo what i done http://jsbin.com/gabavonezi/1/edit and here is what i need http://jsbin.com/dodawoqoqu/1/edit

Comment: @stav You should remove the `+` operators. I had used `+` to convert the operands to numbers. Since the contents start with a letter it returns `NaN` (Not a Number) for all of them.

Comment: Yes, it worked for me but i am using datepicker on input fields containing date and after shorting datepicker stopped working and i reinitialized it again but not workiing..

Comment: Didn't work for me unless I added `? 1 : -1;` at the end of the return string. So the full return string is:

`return $(a).data('_ts') < $(b).data('_ts') ? 1 : -1;`

Answer (score 4):

Look at this site. It looks like this is what you are trying to do.  http://www.kryogenix.org/code/browser/sorttable/

Comment: nice plugin :) Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

when you pass string to `Date` constructor it's format is `month/date/year`.

since your date format is `date-month-year`. you can reformat it using regular expression.

```
$('tr.Entries').sort(function (a, b) {
    return new Date($(a).find($("[data-field-type='date']")).html().replace(/(\d{2})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})/g,'$2/$1/$3')).getTime() < new Date($(b).find($("[data-field-type='date']")).html().replace(/(\d{2})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})/g,'$2/$1/$3')).getTime()
}).appendTo('tbody');
```

Comment: Thanks! you are right  and your change on code work fine. I accepted the Vohuman sugestion becouse that  code i think worked faster on larger data rows