# How to sort date in column table in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, date

Since I am a beginner, I don't know how to start sorting the date column. I have another column which is total price in my table. I managed to sort the price column since it only involves number only.

The codes I provided below is how I successfully sort price column.

[image]

```
//function to sort number
  function sortLowest() {
        var table, rows, switching, i, x, y, shouldSwitch;
        table = document.getElementById("example");
        switching = true;
        while (switching) {
            switching = false;
            rows = table.rows;
            for (i = 1; i < (rows.length - 1); i++) {
                shouldSwitch = false;
                x = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("TD")[6];
                y = rows[i + 1].getElementsByTagName("TD")[6];
                if (parseInt(x.innerHTML.toLowerCase()) > parseInt(y.innerHTML.toLowerCase())) {
                    shouldSwitch = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (shouldSwitch) {
                rows[i].parentNode.insertBefore(rows[i + 1], rows[i]);
                switching = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

Below are the html code

```
  <p id="rating">Filter by Price:
  <select id="myList" class='form-control' style="width: 100%">
  <option id="stylesheet1" value="low">Lowest-Highest</option>
  <option id="stylesheet2" value="high">Highest-Lowest</option>
  </select></p>

<script>
  document.getElementById("myList").onchange = function() {
        var sheet = document.getElementById("myList").value;
        if (sheet == "high") {
            sortHighest();
        } else {
            sortLowest();
        }
        return false
    };
</script>
```

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: Can you also please show the code?

Comment: Do you want to sort in brower with javascript ? Maybe its better to sort the data in your backend over Rest and update your table after the backend response

Comment: Take a look,

https://www.jqueryscript.net/table/Simple-Table-Rows-Sorting-Plugin-with-jQuery.html

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29571613/sort-html-table-rows-by-first-date-column-with-jquery

Comment: don't develop a sort algorithm on your own. Instead use the sort function from array: [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

Comment: @Mary It looks like the `sort` function as mentioned above is what you need. Can you also share the CSS please?

Comment: @Guillaume yeah thats true. May I know CSS for what?

Comment: @Mary to see the full problem and make sure we can help in the best of ways :)

Comment: @Mary Sorry, I meant the HTML. Long day at work.

Comment: @Guillaume please take a look at the code

Comment: @Mary Have a look below please :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would definitely be easier with a sort method but I would assume that you need to use a similar logic as the one above.
You're also dealing with dates so you need to convert your string/text to dates before sorting; meaning using Date.now() or new Date().

I guess you do get the rows with `rows = table.rows;` and that `getElementsByTagName("TD")[7]` gives you the date column (I'm using 7 as an example since you wrote 6 as the price in your description so please use whatever column index is correct to get the dates for your problem).
If these assumptions are correct, you can re-order by doing something like this and using a similar logic as above for dates:

```
        while (switching) {
            switching = false;
            rows = table.rows;
            for (i = 1; i < (rows.length - 1); i++) {
                shouldSwitch = false;
                x = new Date(rows[i].getElementsByTagName("TD")[7].innerHTML.split('/').reverse().join(', '));
                y = new Date(rows[i + 1].getElementsByTagName("TD")[7].innerHTML.split('/').reverse().join(', '));

                if (x > y) {
                    shouldSwitch = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (shouldSwitch) {
                rows[i].parentNode.insertBefore(rows[i + 1], rows[i]);
                switching = true;
            }
        }
```

nb: The reason why I re-ordered '16/09/2019' to be '2019, 09, 16' with `.split('/').reverse().join(', ')` is because something like `new Date('16/09/2019')` does not work as opposed to `new Date('2019, 09, 16')` which does.

Please let me know if this solution solves your issue or if you have any question.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works well. May I know other than join(',') can I used other symbols like join('.') as well?

Comment: Glad it did work :)
Join accepts a string as argument and `new Date` would work with '.' instead of ',' so you can.

Comment: Good explanation there. You just save my day.

Comment: If I want to sort the date by month, how can I do that?

Comment: It's a different matter. You can sort by the middle number `.split('/')[1]` but you would not be able to use `new Date` for that